# How to Extending Core Controller Class twice?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to have tow type of extended controller class, one for admin, and other for the rest.

I create first one named MY_Controller, how to make the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like the first ...

In the file core/Admin_controller.php

```
Class Admin_controller extends CI_Controller{
    ...
}
```

or

```
Class Admin_controller extends MY_Controller{
    ...
}
```

And then ...

```
Class MyFirstAdmin extends Admin_controller{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I got: Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Controller' not found in C:\...\application\controllers\cp.php on line 8

Comment: Review your use, case-sensitive in the class names and files